# dataset in json or xml

Tags: json, xml

I am working on a project that can display the winning numbers for New York Daily lottery results in json or xml. I need the dataset for New York lottery daily drawing results in json or xml. thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do NOT expect SO will do your work. You should come up with your own solution and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). To improve your questions, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Have a poke around [data.ny.gov](https://data.ny.gov/)

Then you could start looking at data sets tagged with [New York Lottery](https://data.ny.gov/browse?tags=new%20york%20lottery).